# Stitching up implicit function theorem to obtain global result?

Tags: real-analysis, implicit-function-theorem

Given $\mathbf{F}: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^m$ which is continuously differentiable, consider a system of equations  such that $\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) = 0$. Suppose that there exists an implicitly defined unique function $\mathbf{y}^*: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}^*(\mathbf{x})) = 0$ (i.e., I do not have a closed form for it but I know that for each $\mathbf{x}$ there exists a unique $\mathbf{y}$ such that $\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) = 0$) , and for all $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, the Jacobian $\nabla_\mathbf{y} \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}^*(\mathbf{x}))$ is invertible.

By the implicit function theorem, I know that there for each $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ exists a set $\mathbf{x} \in U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that the unique restriction of $\mathbf{y}^*$ to $U$ is continuously differentiable.

Does the existence of a globally unique $\mathbf{y}^*$ imply the global continuous differentiability of $\mathbf{y}^*$? That is, can I stitch up the locally continuous derivative maps to obtain a globally continuous derivative map?

Comment: If you start from a global solution, you can use the implicit function theorem to show regularity. However, in general you cannot patch together local solutions to get a global one.

Comment: The "however" part is confusing me. Just to be sure, given a global solution that exists uniquely, the formula for the derivative given by the implicit function theorem holds globally? If so, how would I prove this because I am not sure how to approach it. It seems very intuitive but it is not clear to me how to argue it.

Comment: If the global solution exists and is differentiable then the formula for the derivative follows from just differentiating. You do not need the implicit function theorem.

Comment: My issue is that I do not have a closed form for $y^*$. Are you saying I should be implicitly differentiating?

Comment: If $F(x,y^*(x)) = 0$ then $F_x(x,y^*(x))+ F_y(x,y^*(x))y_x^*(x) = 0$. The formula follows from invertibility.

Comment: Oh, okay and so then you're saying assuming some regularity conditions on $F_x(x,y^*(x)$ and $F_y(x,y^*(x))$ such that $y^*_x(x)$ is continuously differentiable would be the way to prove global continuous differentiability?

Comment: If the Jacobian is invertible then you can use that.

Comment: Awesome, makes sense! So the point is, we can get to that conclusion without the IFT then?

Comment: @copper.hat One (last, I promise) question! Even if $\mathbf{y}_{\mathbf{x}}^*(\mathbf{x}) = [F_x(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}^*(\mathbf{x}))]^{-1} F_x(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}^*(\mathbf{x}))$ is well defined, how do we know that $\mathbf{y}^*(\mathbf{x})$ is continuous so as to guarantee that $\mathbf{y}_{\mathbf{x}}^*(\mathbf{x})$ is continuous? Or do we not need that for continuous differentiability of $\mathbf{y}^*(\mathbf{x})$?

Comment: @Denizalp Since $F$ is $C^1$ then $F_x,F_y$ are continuous and hence so is $y_x^*$.

Comment: This seems so odd because could $y^*(x)$ not be discontinuous? We are composing $F_x$ and $F_y$ with $y^*(x)$ to obtain $y_x^*(x)$ so it feels like $y_x^*(x)$ could also be discontinuous. Any intuition?

Comment: @copper.hat oh, nevermind, in my setting $y^*(x)$ is continuous! Thanks a ton!!!